# AssemblyInitialize and AssemblyCleanup not triggering

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, mstest

In MSTEST, I want to send out a mail once all the test run has been completed.

Currently I have included my code to send mail in the [TestCleanup] method in MSTEST. The problem is, the mail is sending for each test cases. If I run more than one test case from TestExplorer in Visual Studio, the mail is going for every test cases.

I want to send out a single mail once all the test cases are executed. Also I tried to include my mailing part in the [AssemblyCleanup] method in MSTest. But both the [AssemblyInitialize] and [AssemblyCleanup] are not triggering while executing the test cases.

**Is there any way to know, how many test cases are queued for running while executing in MSTest programmatically?**

Or

**Is there any way to trigger the [AssemblyInitialize] and [AssemblyCleanup] ?**

Sample Code:

```
     [TestClass]
 public abstract class MasterClass
    {
     [AssemblyInitialize] -- Not triggering
            public virtual void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
            {
                Reports.PrintLog("------------------ Test Started ------------------");
            }
    
      [AssemblyCleanup] -- Not triggering
            public virtual void AssemblyCleanup()
            {
            
                SendEmail(MailTo, attachment);
            }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This method should be `static` as they are on the whole assembly and not on a specific instance.

Check Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms245278(v=vs.90)).

Comment: [AssemblyInitialize] and [AssemblyCleanup] are not triggering even though makes the method as Static.

Answer (score 0):

MSTest cannot instantiate your abstract class. So it cannot test it.

And the method should be static